# shutil.move cannot move between drives

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, shutil

I am trying to move files to a mapped network drive that I have permissions for.
But it does not work. There have been other posts with this issue, but none of them have an answer. Anybody know what the deal is?

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 557, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: 'C:\\Users\\opcon\\pyscripts\\crif\\129049_24360_20200102223356_.csv' -> 'G:\\b_129049_24360_20200102223356_.csv'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/opcon/pyscripts/fix_and_scan_crifloans.py", line 379, in fix_crifloan_csvs_exe
    shutil.move(local_full_file_name, full_file_name_b)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 571, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'G:\\b_129049_24360_20200102223356_.csv'
```

[image: It looks like I should have access]

[image: But evidently I don't have access]

Comment: Yeah, looks like you can't write directly to the drive. Can you make a folder under `G:` using explorer, and try to copy to that?

Comment: When I was doing stuff with networked drives in python I found that most issues could be fixed by putting the network path of the drive, not the letter, e.g `\\\\SERVER\\FOLDER\\SUBFOLDER` just remember to replace each "\" in the pathname with "\\"

Comment: @KJTHoward. Or use `r` prefix

Comment: I'm trying everything, nothing seems to work. No matter what it fails on the *with open(G-FILE-dst, 'wb') as fdst:* and it fails with Permission[13] - I've tried many variations, r, // ////, subfolders, etc. as long as it is on G it gets the permission error

Comment: I discovered that my user 'OpCon' on Opcon server seems to have only readonly privileges to that directory (even though it looks like they have other rights from my first attached image). I tried and create a new file in there through windows explorer and I got a permission required message. So at least the python is consistent with the windows

Comment: ...given which, why are you still asking a question here, now that you know it's an OS permissions issue rather than a problem with your code?

Comment: Well I had to figure that out first, but I am going to ask again somewhere else (this one is for the windows gurus)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue with my Windows Permissions, this just was not immediately evident as windows says I should have permissions.